# sql update for 1 table included where clause 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I made Select statement:

```
Select table1.id, table1.date, table1.name, table2.text
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
where table2.date =< '20-05-2017'
and table2.date > '20-05-2017'
and table2.statement = '%text%'
```

this worked, but now i have to update it, but also there comes a third table
so i need

```
Update table1
set table1.groupid = 10
where table2.date =< '20-05-2017'
and table2.date > '20-05-2017'
and table2.statement = '%text%'
and table3.term = 100
```

how can i join all these tables so my statement worked, table3.otherid=table1.otherid there is a lot of rows, so i cannt take them in n++ and form them like this for all

```
update table1
set table1.groupid = 
where table1.id in (all the id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mysql 
You could use an update with inner join
(i have use for table3 inner join you condition table3.otherid=table1.otherid   .. be sure this is correct  )

```
  Update table1
  inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
  inner join table3 on table3.otherid=table1.otherid 
  set table1.groupid = 10
  where table2.date =< '20-05-2017'
  and table2.date > '20-05-2017'
  and table2.statement = '%text%'
  and table3.term = 100
```

If  you are using postgresql you could use this sintax

```
  Update table1 t1
  set t1.groupid = 10
  FROM table1 ttt1
  inner join table2 on ttt1.id=table2.id
  inner join table3 on table3.otherid=ttt1.otherid 
  where table2.date =< '20-05-2017'
  and table2.date > '20-05-2017'
  and table2.statement = '%text%'
  and table3.term = 100
```

Comment: mm,

Update table1
  inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
  inner join table3 on table3.otherid=table1.otherid 
  set table1.groupid = 10
  where table2.date =< '20-05-2017'
  and table2.date > '20-05-2017'
  and table2.statement = '%text%'
  and table3.term = 100
writing by example i had a syntax error ERROR: syntax error at or near "inner" SQL state: 42601

Comment: how it would be with postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Update-Join

```
update table1
    inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
    inner join table3.otherid=table1.otherid
set table1.groupid = 10
where table2.date =< '20-05-2017'
    and table2.date > '20-05-2017'
    and table2.statement = '%text%'
    and table3.term = 100
```

If that is not what you are looking for, please explain clearly your question.

Answer (score 0):

hmm,

```
Update table1
  inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
  inner join table3 on table3.otherid=table1.otherid 
  set table1.groupid = 10
  where table2.date =< '20-05-2017'
  and table2.date > '20-05-2017'
  and table2.statement = '%text%'
  and table3.term = 100
```

writing by example i had a syntax error
ERROR: syntax error at or near "inner"
SQL state: 42601